# Silverlight: ScrollIntoView, find the column number where a control is

Tags: .net, silverlight, datagrid

I need to scroll into a specific cell in a datagrid in silverlight, i'm trying to use the ScrollIntoView method, but I need the column and I don't have it.

How can I scroll into a specific cell in a datagrid control?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think using of `Dispatcher` will solve your problem.

Comment: If you want some examples or explanation - just let me know.